# Google Authorization flow for desktop applications

Tags: api, task

Is there a way of doing the google OAuth 2.0 authorization without opening the browser page?
I want to do the Authentication and Authorization part programatically, given the user's mail address and password.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot done this by username and password  normal OAuth flow. But in Exception you can do this by `Service accounts`. Read more [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

By service account end-user don't need to be involved each time.